# Image upload form gives me "No such file or directory" error

Tags: php

PHP:

```
if((isset($_POST['title']))&&(isset($_POST['body']))){ 

$maxSize = 4000; 
$acceptType = array( 
     'png' => 'image/png',
     'jpe' => 'image/jpeg',
     'jpeg' => 'image/jpeg',
     'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
     'gif' => 'image/gif',
);

$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']); 
$body = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['body']); 


if((isset($_FILES['image']))&&(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]))){ 

   $image_dest = "/it/images/".rand(1,1000)."-".basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

   if($_FILES['image']['size'] <= $maxSize*1024) {

       if(in_array($_FILES['image']['type'], $acceptType)) {

           if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $image_dest)) // line 44
                $message="Ok";
        }
   }



}
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="createblog.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>
        <label>Title:</label>
        <input type="text" size="100" name="title">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Image:</label>
        <input type="file" name="image">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Image Caption:</label>
        <input type="text" size="100" name="imagecaption">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="editor1">Body:</label>
        <textarea class="ckeditor" cols="50" id="editor1" name="body" rows="10"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Why I get this error ?

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/it/images/865-Star_Trek_Logo.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/08/1936/html/it/createblog.php on line 44

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/php0hvJSh' to '/it/images/865-Star_Trek_Logo.jpg' in /home/content/08/1936/html/it/createblog.php on line 44
```

Comment: What is not clear from the error message? `No such file or directory`

Comment: is there a folder with the name "it" in your root directory of the server?

Comment: yes, there is a folder with the name "it" and in this folder there is another folder with the name "images".

Comment: In the _*root*_ directory? Or in `/home/content/08/1936/html/it/images/`

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the full path:

```
$image_dest = "/home/content/08/1936/html/it/images/".rand(1,1000)."-".basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
```

Comment: $image_dest is the location of the file _with_ the filename, thus it is not, and does not need to be a directory.

Comment: /images/ is the directory, `rand(1,1000)."-".basename($_FILES['image']['name']` is the generated file name, not a directory.

Answer (score 1):

The begining of your $image_dest should be:

```
/home/content/08/1936/html/it/images/
```

You are trying to use a relative path, while an absolute path is required, so:

```
$image_dest = "/home/content/08/1936/html/it/images/".rand(1,1000)."-".basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
```

Also note that you must chmod your `images` directory to `777` to allow files to be uploaded to it.